# How to return correct count in star schema

Tags: sql, sql-server, data-warehouse

I've run into an issue returning a count that reflects the question I'm trying to answer in the following query:

```
select s.sitename, c.primarylanguage, count(primarylanguage)
from cor.sites s
join cor.scores cs on s.id = cs.siteid
join cor.children c on c.id = cs.childid
group by s.sitename, c.primarylanguage
order by s.sitename;
```

The sitename and primarylanguage are correct just not the count. I want to return the sitename joined with all languages spoken at the site. Then I want a count of how many children speak that language at that site. My current query sums all the rows in the fact table (cor.scores) instead of telling me how many children speak a language at a site.

Context:
Primary language is found in the cor.children dimension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `distinct` keyword as follows:

```
count(distinct c.id)
```

Comment: This is it! Thanks.

Comment: @PJ.SQL the best SO thanks is an answer accept :) do not hesitate!